# Webstorm turn off new spaces in anonymous function declaration

Tags: javascript, webstorm

e.g. I have this:

```
exports.getsertHexId = function (table, hex) {
```

Webstorm 8's auto-indent is creating the space between the keyword `function` and the open paren `(`.

Its settings spaces options cover:

- Function declaration parentheses
- Function call parentheses
- 'if' parentheses
- . . .

Confused since this should be covered under function declaration parentheses I thought. Can this be properly configured? Is it a bug?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Scroll down further and it's the option "In function expression." Because `function() { ... }` is an expression which returns a value, that value being a function.

[image]

Comment: Why they did this. Is that part of some new standard ? I tried to use google js standard but after import this was breaking it.