# PHPStorm disable spaces before anonymous function parentheses

Tags: php, coding-style, phpstorm

Similar to this question: [Webstorm turn off new spaces in anonymous function declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22868739/webstorm-turn-off-new-spaces-in-anonymous-function-declaration)

Just trying to disable anonymous function call spaces.

```
$this->call(function ()
{
  return 'test';
});
```

I'd like the following

```
$this->call(function()
{
  return 'test';
});
```

On the question linked above, the answer was provided for JS coding styles, but I'm looking for PHP answers.

Answer (score 1):

As of now with PhpStorm 7.1 this is not, possible.
The option under JavaScript Style is "function expression". They did not implement that or something for callbacks for php.

Answer (score 1):

Its is a known bug in PHPStorm and being tracked in [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-24603) on their issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

It is an included option now, you find it under **Settings** > **Editor** > **Code Style** > **PHP** > **Spaces**.

[image: Anonymous function parentheses PHPStorm]